# Always exclude property from Entity Framework 4 Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a user entity with the following properties that map to a field in the database:

```
Id         int  
Username   varchar(25)  
Password   binary(64)   
Salt       binary(64)   
Name       varchar(50)  
Locked     bit
```

What I don't want to do is always return the Password and Salt for *every* query. But for certain queries, I do want to be able to check the password (`from u in db.Users where u.Password == password select u`) or set the Password/Salt fields. I don't want 128B *always* going over the wire when it's never needed.

I tried setting the property's getter to private, but that stopped me from using it in LINQ. Basically it would be cool if I could set a property to *always lazy load*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a User Repository that uses a POCO to store the User without the Password and Salt fields.

The Repository handles calling Entity Framework and populating your POCO with its data.

```
namespace MyCompany.Data.Repositories
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Locked { get; private set; }
    }

    public class UserRepository
    {
        public User GetAll() { }
        public User GetById() { }

        // Add your check password method here
    }
}
```

Comment: So then what happens to the auto-generated User class?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - You utilize it inside your Repository class (and restrict its use elsewhere).

Comment: The problem then becomes that I have two User classes (though from different namespaces). Isn't this cumbersome?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - When using Repositories, the consumer shouldn't need access to the EF generated classes at all. Therefore they should only see your MyCompany.Data.Repositories.User class.